# Cómo hago para imprimir un arreglo C++

Tags: c++, array

```
#include<iostream>//biblioteca
#include<conio.h>//biblioteca

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arreglo[2],numeros[2];//el array numeros es almacenado dentro del array arreglo
    int capcontador,nocapcontador;
    
    for(int k=0; k<=2; k++){
        cout<<"Ingrese el arreglo "<<k+1<<"\n"; 
    
        for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
            cout<<"Ingrese la posicion "<<i<<" del arreglo: ";cin>>numeros[i];
        }

        if(numeros[0]==numeros[2]){
            cout<<"\nes capicua \n";
            capcontador++;
        }else{
            cout<<"\nno es capicua \n";
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nnumeros capicuas: "<<capcontador<<endl;
    cout<<"numeros no capicuas: "<<8-capcontador<<endl;

    for(int k=0;k<2;k++){
        //**Aquí debería ir el código para imprimir el arreglo que se llama arreglo**

        cout<<arreglo[k]; //talvez no este bien usar la varible k
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema ni qué quieres hacer con ese código. Estás imprimiendo bien el arreglo con el último for. El único inconveniente es que parecerá que ves un solo número porque no los separas de ninguna manera. Podrías agregar un espacio en medio: `cout << arreglo[k] << ' ';`

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo inferir de tu programa deseas ingresar en un arreglo tres numeros enteros, uno en cada posición y determinar si el arreglo es o no es capicua (Capicua quiere decir que si coloca el arreglo de forma inversa, serán los mismos números).

Partiendo de esto

- El primer error que tienes es en la declaración del arreglo llamado "numeros".

Puedo suponer que quieres ingresar tres elementos, por lo que en la declaración del arreglo quedaría de la siguiete forma:

```
int numeros[3];
```

- El segundo error que tienes es en los contadores, en C++ tienes que indicar específicamente en que numero deseas que comience el contador, por lo que esa parte del codigo quedaria de la siguiente forma:

  int capcontador = 0 , nocapcontador = 0;
- El tercer error que tienes es que nunca usas la variable "nocapcontador" que funciona como contador para los que no son capicuas, por lo que esa condicional quedaría de la siguiente forma:

  ```
   if(numeros[0]==numeros[2]){
       cout<<"\nes capicua \n";
       capcontador++;
   }else{
       cout<<"\nno es capicua \n";
       nocapcontador++;
   }
  ```

Junto con este punto también tengo que mencionar que en la impresion de los que no son capicuas tienes lo siguiente:

```
cout<<"numeros no capicuas: "<<8-capcontador<<endl;
```

El error esta en el "-8capcontador". Alli lo que quieres hacer es imprimir la variable "nocapcontador" por lo que quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
cout<<"numeros no capicuas: "<<nocapcontador<<endl;
```

- Y por último el arreglo que tienes al final. Sinceramente no entiendo para que quieres imprimir ese ultimo arreglo si nunca lo utilizas a lo largo del programa, por lo que ese último trozo de codigo no sirve para absolutamente nada.

Pero en caso tal de que quieras imprimir un arreglo te respondo a tu duda de que

> Tal vez no este bien usar la variable k

No te preocupes, si esta bien, y sí la utilizaste bien si piensas imprimir un arreglo de dos elementos.

Habiendo dicho todo esto, el código completo, quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arreglo[2],numeros[3];//Recordar que el arreglo[2] no se utiliza en todo el programa por lo que no toqué esa parte
    int capcontador = 0, nocapcontador = 0;
    
    for(int k=0; k<=2; k++){
        cout<<"Ingrese el arreglo "<<k+1<<"\n"; 
    
        for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
            cout<<"Ingrese la posicion "<<i<<" del arreglo: ";
            cin>>numeros[i];
        }

        if(numeros[0]==numeros[2]){
            cout<<"Es capicua \n\n";
            capcontador++;
        }else{
            cout<<"No es capicua \n\n";
            nocapcontador++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nNumeros capicuas: "<<capcontador<<endl;
    cout<<"Numeros no capicuas: "<<nocapcontador<<endl;

/*       
Esta impresion del arreglo no sirve de nada 
porque el arreglo que se quiere imprimir no se utiliza nunca en el programa
por lo que coloqué esta parte en comentarios

    for(int k=0;k<2;k++){
        cout<<arreglo[k]<<endl;
    }
*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. solucionaste el problema del contador de numeros no capicuas. Pero como haria para imprimir los tres arrays almacenados en arreglo[2](osea los 3 numeros capicuas)? gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Agrego el problema inicial: /*Formar un arreglo con 8 números de 3 cifras procedentes del teclado de la consola.
Implementar un programa para ver solo los números capicúas del arreglo e indicar
cuantos cumplen esta condición.*/

Answer (score 0):

Ahora que me enviaste el enunciado, he comprendido el problema a solucionar.
Recomiendo tener comprensión lectora, analizar parte por parte y despacio el enunciado para poder entenderlo, esto lo digo por lo siguiente:

- La primera parte del enunciado dice:

> Formar **UN** arreglo **CON** 8 números.

Esta parte es bastante clara, solo se debe utilizar **UN** solo arreglo

- La segunda parte del enunciado dice:

> De 3 cifras procedentes del teclado

Es decir que cada elemento del arreglo, o cada numero que se ingrese en el arreglo debe tener 3 cifras y el usuario debe ingresar los números.

- El resto nos dice solo que mostremos los numeros capicuas ingresados en el arreglo de 8 numeros e indicar cuantos hay.

Con base a lo analizado he hecho el siguiente código, comentado paso a paso para que se pueda entender de forma clara:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arreglo[8]; //Declaro el arreglo con tamaño para 8 numeros
    int capcontador = 0; //contador de numeros capicúas
    
    //Variables para saber cuales numeros son capicua
    int num,temp,numinv,b;
    
    //Ingreso los 8 numeros de 3 digitos cada uno a traves de consola (Asegurarse que sean tres digitos)
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese el valor "<<i+1<<" del Arreglo: ";
        cin>>arreglo[i];
    }

    //Analizo cada elemento del arreglo y solo imprimo los que son capicuas
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        //Logica para saber si el numero en cada posicion del arreglo es capicua
        num = arreglo[i];
        numinv=0;
        temp=arreglo[i];
        while(num > 0){
            b = num%10;
            numinv = b + numinv*10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        
        //Impresion de los que son capicuas
        if(numinv==temp){
            capcontador++;
            if(capcontador == 1){
             cout<<"Los numeros Capicuas son: "<<endl;   
            }
            cout<<arreglo[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
    
    //En caso de que no se haya ingresado ningun numero capicua
    if(capcontador == 0){
        cout<<"No hay numeros capicuas"<<endl;
    }
     //En caso de que se ingresen numeros capicuas
    else{
        cout<<"Hay "<<capcontador<<" Numeros Capicuas"<<endl;
        cout<<"Y hay "<<8-capcontador<<" Numeros que NO son Capicuas"<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

La logica para obtener un número capicua esta bien explicada en el siguiente video que te recomiendo ver para que puedas entender mejor:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88Sg0-KZkXw

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Gracias. completamente solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Formar un arreglo con 8 números de 3 cifras procedentes del teclado de la 
consola. Implementar un programa para ver los números capicúas y no capicuas del 
arreglo e indicar cuantos cumplen esta condición.*/
#include <iostream>
## Código completo ##
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arreglo[8]; //Declaro el arreglo con tamaño para 8 numeros
    int capcontador = 0; //contador de numeros capicúas
    int nocapcontador = 0; //contador de numeros capicúas

//Variables para saber cuales numeros son capicua
int num,temp,numinv,b;

//Ingreso los 8 numeros de 3 digitos cada uno a traves de consola (Asegurarse 
que sean tres digitos)
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese el valor "<<i+1<<" del Arreglo: ";
    cin>>arreglo[i];
}


//Analizo cada elemento del arreglo y solo imprimo los que son capicuas
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    //Logica para saber si el numero en cada posicion del arreglo es capicua
    num = arreglo[i];
    numinv=0;
    temp=arreglo[i];
    while(num > 0){
        b = num%10;
        numinv = b + numinv*10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    
    //Impresion de los que son capicuas
    if(numinv==temp){
        capcontador++;
        if(capcontador == 1){
         cout<<"Los numeros Capicuas son: "<<endl;   
        }
        cout<<arreglo[i]<<endl;
    } 
        
    }    

for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    //Logica para saber si el numero en cada posicion del arreglo es capicua
    num = arreglo[i];
    numinv=0;
    temp=arreglo[i];
    while(num > 0){
        b = num%10;
        numinv = b + numinv*10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    
    //Impresion de los que no son capicuas
    if(numinv!=temp){
        nocapcontador++;
        if(nocapcontador == 1){
         cout<<"Los numeros no Capicuas son: "<<endl;   
        }
        cout<<arreglo[i]<<endl;
    }     
}


//En caso de que no se haya ingresado ningun numero capicua
if(capcontador == 0){
    cout<<"No hay numeros capicuas"<<endl;
}
 //En caso de que se ingresen numeros capicuas
else{
    cout<<"Hay "<<capcontador<<" Numeros Capicuas"<<endl;
    cout<<"Y hay "<<nocapcontador<<" Numeros que NO son Capicuas"<<endl;
    
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a tu pregunta? Lee [answer]. Además, debes [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.